# Can't populate a 2 dimensional array in Excel-VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, vba

I'm comparing some information contained in 2 different sheets. The validation is working as expected. From that comparison I have to get two values, it was working with one, because I was populating a 1D array. Now that I got a 2D array it doesn't seem to be getting populated and I can't figure why. Here is my code.

```
Private Sub btngenerar_Click()

    Dim wscasos As Worksheet
    Dim wstareas As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range
    Dim cel2 As Range
    Dim vrep As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim flag As Integer
    Dim resultado() As Variant
    Dim x As Long


    Set wscasos = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Filtrados")
    Set wstareas = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tareas")

    With wscasos
        Set r1 = .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("B:B").Column).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With wstareas
        Set r2 = .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("C:C").Column).End(xlUp))
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cel1 In r1
        With Application
            Set cel2 = .Index(r2, .Match(cel1.Value, r2, 0))
            If Err = 0 Then
                vrep = .WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r2, cel1.Value)
                For i = 1 To vrep
                    If cel2.Offset(i - 1, 4) = "Cerrado" Then
                        flag = flag + 1
                    Else
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next i
                If flag = vrep Then
                    ReDim Preserve resultado(x, 1)
                    resultado(x, 0) = cel1.Value
                    resultado(x, 1) = cel1.Offset(, 8).Value
                    x = x + 1
                End If
            End If
            Err.Clear
            flag = 0
        End With
    Next cel1

    i = 0
    j = 0

    Sheets("Reporte").Range("A1").Select
    For i = LBound(resultado, 1) To UBound(resultado, 1)
        For j = LBound(resultado, 2) To UBound(resultado, 2)
            ActiveCell.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value = resultado(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm a bit rusty and prolly it's a simple fix, I hope you can help me out to find the error. Thanks a lot in advance. Here is where I populate the array:

```
            If flag = vrep Then
                ReDim Preserve resultado(x, 1)
                resultado(x, 0) = cel1.Value
                resultado(x, 1) = cel1.Offset(, 8).Value
                x = x + 1
            End If
```

Comment: 1. Remove the `On Error Resume Next` it is hiding the needed errors that will help you debug your code.  2.  You did not give an initial dimension to `resultado` before trying to `redim preserve` put `Redim resultado(0,1)` before your loop.  3.  You can only change the last dimension with `redim preserve` so you will need to flip your array and transpose it later.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed the `On Error Resume Next` and I got Error 9: Subindex out of interval. I gave an initial dimension to `resultado`. Now gotta look into that error and check the point 3, I'm not so sure about how to do it though.

Comment: What's your Base?  [`Option Base 0`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx) will ensure that your arrays are `0 TO (n-1)`, not `1 TO n` by default, or you can specify in the ReDim: `ReDim Preserve resultado(0 TO x, 0 TO 1)`

Comment: I'm using the default base 0, will make it explicit and see if something changes, because so far I haven't been able to fix it